# "segmentation fault (core dumped)", when trying to run Tensorboard from terminal

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a small RNN for classifying signals over 10 classes. The network gives me around 0.2-0.4% error. Now I am trying to visualize the network using tensor board.

- I have created summary ops for the nodes I want to check.(such a weight, bias, cost etc).
- I have merged all the summaries.
- Launched tensorflow session and tried writing the data to log directory using

  *writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/home/raisa/PycharmProjects/graphs")*
- The code runs without any error.
- Then I tried to run tensorboard with the command
- ***tensorboard --logdir=/home/raisa/PycharmProjects/graph***

This gives me error **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

> I have tensoorflow 0.8.0. 
>   I am also getting a warning  saying
>
> **WARNING:tensorflow:Passing a `GraphDef` to the SummaryWriter is
>   deprecated. Pass a `Graph` object instead, such as `sess.graph`.**

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It might be that it's being incorrectly saved? It seems like you're passing in GraphDef object to the summary writer instead of the session itself.

Comment: How can I pass the object to session? @Steven

Comment: summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/directory/to/save/to", sess.graph)

Comment: 0.8 is very old, 0.11.0rc2 is the latest version

Answer (score 1):

```
sess = tf.Session()

summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/directory/to/save/to", sess.graph) 

step = 1
merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
summary = sess.run([merged])
summary_writer.add_summary(summary, step)
```